# Sort legend items up and down with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, legend

I work with arcmap 10.2.2 and I have 10 mxd's in one folder. I try to sort the legend items with a python code by moving the legend items up\down and i want that the layers in the TOC stay as is. I saw this question "[Resequencing Legend Items using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/resequencing-legend-items-using-arcpy)" but didn't get my answer from it.
I try this code but it doesn't work:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string
import arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env


env.workspace = r"C:\Project"
for mxdname in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    print mxdname
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\\" + mxdname)
    legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"LEGEND_ELEMENT")[0]
    for lyr in legend.listLegendItemLayers():
        if lyr.name == "atikot":
            legend.moveItem(lyr)
            print 'move'
    mxd.save()
del mxd
```

Comment: When you run that code what happens?  Saying "doesn't work" is far less helpful than, for example, an error message or telling us that there was no error but also no alteration to the order of items in the legend element.

Comment: this is en error: AttributeError: 'LegendElement' object has no attribute 'moveItem'

Comment: That error message is to be expected because the [LEGEND_ELEMENT class does not have a `moveitem` method](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/legendelement-class.htm#M2_GUID-BA2C3D94-8CA7-42FC-9E85-A4E7EAD78F83).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think that this is a duplicate of [Resequencing Legend Items using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6794/resequencing-legend-items-using-arcpy) where I think [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/6800) provides the way to a very messy workaround/procedure that would involve basically:

1. removing all layers from your Table of Contents,
2. setting autoAdd to True,
3. adding the layers back in the order you want for your legend,
4. removing all layers from your Table of Contents again,
5. setting autoAdd to False
6. adding the layers back in the order you want for your Table of Contents

Alternatively, there is an existing ArcGIS Idea called [Reorder legend items with arcpy.mapping](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E00000005ANWIA2) which could do with some fleshing out but is more along the lines of what I think you are after.